# Css background-image, image serving by tornado

Tags: python, css, image, tornado

I have an image server in tornado, the code is:

```
class Index(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       header = "image/png"
       ifile = open("image.png","r")
       self.add_header("Content-Type",header) 
       self.write(ifile.read())
```

I used this image in `<img src="http://localhost:8888/img" />` and this works fine but it doesn't work when called in a css background-image, example: `<div style="background-image:url(http://localhost:8888/img)"></div>` .

Comment: You want `<div style="background-image:url(http://localhost:8888/img)">`.  It's a `=`, not a `:`, when specifying attributes in html.

Comment: Thanks @metatoaster for your comment, I understand what you're saying, the "style" attribute contains a code CSS "background-image: url (http: // localhost: 8888 / img)", and the css properties use " : " , thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that when using css validates the url of the image or the extension of this ?, I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

your is correct but height of `dev` is `0` and for this resean not shown.

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://localhost:8888/img); min-height: 100px; background-repeat: repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
```